# Scheduled task deleting itself

Tags: powershell, scheduled-task

I am using PowerShell to create scheduled tasks on my local machine, the Scheduled Task runs a PowerShell script to PowerShell remote into a server and copy files.

When I run the Scheduled task using the option: - `Run when user is logged on or not` - the task runs and straight away deletes the task - any ideas what's going on, when I use my account when I am logged on it works as expected

Comment: When using option "..." what ? Also provide the Powershell command you use to create the Scheduled Task

Comment: are you copying over mapped drives ? If so, add a `net use` and or `test-path` command inside the script to fix.  Or alternatively leave script as is and check the `Run only when user is logged on` button so that your script can find mapped drives even while you are logged off.